# How can I kick someone from a Steam group?

Tags: steam

Someone added me and well, randomly used vulgar words against me and me family. They seem to be a member of the group I am an admin at, and I want to kick them as they might target the group's discussions too, however I can't find a way to kick them.

How can I kick someone from our group so that they don't try to attack our discussions (when we are offline etc)?

Comment: ...Unfriend and block them?  Can't send you messages if they don't friend you.

Comment: @Frank I already did that, I'm trying to kick them from our group so that they don't try to attack our discussions etc.

Comment: You may want to clarify that, then.  It sounds like you're talking about messages, to me.

Comment: This might come up if/when I run for mod: On Steam groups, you have to be predictive and alert. Once all admins are offline, they can damage you critically. On SE, community moderation is a thing. Most spam gets removed before mods even see it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the main page of the steam group. This is the page you land on when you click the group for example from your profile page. On the right you should see a menu such as pictured below.

[image: Side menu]

Click "Manage Group Members" (http://steamcommunity.com/groups/[yourgroupname]/membersManage). Follow the instructions in the top of the page: Click the "x" icon next to this rude person's name.

[image: X marks the spot]

Comment: Thanks, accepting. What link does Manage Group Members have?

Comment: http://steamcommunity.com/groups/<yourgroupname>/membersManage

Comment: The page where you can see forum bans is http://steamcommunity.com/groups/<yourgroupname>/forumBanManage

Comment: thanks :) Some links aren't visible to me but I can still use them.

Comment: @Sumurai8 Apologies -- my intent wasn't to hijack your post, just to add what I thought was _very_ relevant information that I (incorrectly) assumed to be true, given that it came from the [official support page](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=2092-QLZX-8453) of the software in question. As a relative newcomer to Arqade, when is it appropriate to edit a question rather than post a comment? The reason I did so in this case is because I thought part of the answer was missing (though I was wrong). If the information had been correct, would the edit have been acceptable?

Comment: It is appropriate to edit a post if you want to correct typos, grammar etc. Otherwise only edit a post if the original poster intended to say something like what you want to post. In this case the note read like "this answer is not correct", which would be more appropriate in a comment, or as a new answer that elaborates more on why it is not possible to kick that member. - In this case I probably would have accepted the edit if steam wouldn't let me kick people if the group was public, but it wasn't, so I had little choice than to reject it in this case.